# I have tried solving this problem, encountered a maximum recursion depth exceeded error

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am a bit of a noob, please go easy on me.

I'm trying to solve [this](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/7).

The [input](https://del.dog/korerufuvy.txt) I'm using.

So I have written code using mammoth amount of input and it keeps on piling up every time function is called.

I want to understand how to approach this and not get the `Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded Error`

```
count = 0
#a #I assign the whole input here

def count_bag(x):
    #a #I assign the whole input here again
    
    for x in a:
        if x == "other bags":
            continue
        elif "shiny gold" in a[x]:
            global count
            count += 1
            break
        else:
            for y in a[x]:
                count_bag(y)



count_bag(a)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python the recursion depth is limited for most compilers, so if you want to do some deep recursion you can use `sys.setrecursionlimit(some value)` to get over this issue

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```

Comment: unfortunately on using this, the python shell restarts automatically.

Comment: what ide are you using, you can see results in an online ide 
https://leetcode.com/playground/new/empty

Comment: I'm using the built-in IDLE that comes with python installation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a queue and skip the recursion? That way, you don't even need to use a global count variable. I haven't compiled/linted this or anything, but something like this:

```
def count_bag(x, a):
    
    count = 0
    to_process = list()
    to_process.extend(x)
    while len(to_process) > 0:
        item = to_process.pop(0) # pop item off front of list
        if item == 'other bags':
            continue
        elif 'shiny gold' in a[item]:
            count += 1
        else:
            for y in a[item]:
                to_process.extend(y)
    return count
```

Comment: actually my input is a dictionary as you have mentioned here as `a`, but what would be `x` while calling the function?

Comment: hey @djhasskin987 thanks for the tip. I got a new perspective.